# How to add render slot with python?

Tags: python

Override method work only if I have opened image editor and "Render Result" is selected there

```
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR':
        override = bpy.context.copy()
        override['area'] = area
        bpy.ops.image.add_render_slot(override)
        break
```

Comment: add line `bpy.context.area.ui_type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'` to switch to image editor. your code will give poll failed error, see for more info on overriding: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/270716/142292

Comment: ahhh i see your problem. let me see.. hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will switch the *Editor Type* to `IMAGE_EDITOR` and set the active image as `bpy.data.images['Render Result']`.

```
import bpy

area_type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'

bpy.context.area.ui_type = area_type # or use (bpy.context.window.screen.areas[5].ui_type = area_type) to change another area to image editor  

areas  = [area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == area_type]
area = areas[0]
area.spaces.active.image = bpy.data.images['Render Result']

override = {
    'window': bpy.context.window,
    'screen': bpy.context.window.screen,
    'area': area,
    'region': [region for region in area.regions if region.type == 'WINDOW'][0],
}

bpy.ops.image.add_render_slot(override)
```

Comment: ps: this is deprecated way of context overriding, see [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/270716/142292) for the new way of context overriding.